# Qiskit: Can I run real experiments in QPUs with OOP structured code?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, programming

The question might be naive, but I'm hesitant to design my algorithm in a complex, Object-Oriented scheme (custom classes, objects etc.). My fear is that current frameworks (e.g. ibmq, qiskit-runtime) don't support it.

Is this the case? Can I verify/reject this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider Qiskit as a classical *interface* between QPU and classical computer. You use classical programming language to prepare quantum circuit. Before sending the circuit to QPU you are still in classical world and you can do anything Python allows - use all other Python libraries, connect to SQL databases or other data sources etc. Even if you call already prepared algorithms from Qiskit libraries you do so classically. Once you call procedure for running the computation on QPU, your algorithm is transpiled to native quantum gates of particular QPU. This is also classical process. Only after that (again classical) electronic set up QPU and run the algorithm in *quantum world*. After measurement, you receive classical data and you can post-process them in Qiskit, again classically.

To sum up, you can use any programming paradigm supported by Python. From your point of view, everything is done classically and QPU is just a device controlled by your classical program using Qiskit libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Qiskit doesn't enforce any restrictions on how you organize you code. You can use OOP concepts as long as the result circuit is an instance of [QuantumCircuit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html) class or a subclass of it.